# Chrome window onunload event

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome

I'm trying to execute the following code

```
window.onunload = function () { 
     var sTag = document.createElement('script'); 
     sTag.src = 'mysrc'; 
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sTag); 
     return false; };
}
```

Itseems to work fine in FF but in chrome I'm getting the download status as cancelled as soon as the unload event is fired. I saw some posts in SO with ajax solutions but I'm executing this script inside a cross domain iframe. Im just trying to log the time for which my api was live in a page per visitor. So, I'm sending some time log information on unload of the page. Is there any work around for the above?

Comment: I doubt you can rely on the browser to stick around long enough for your script element to load.

Comment: Expecting the same what u have mentioned I tried using an `new Image()` call and it seem to work fine. Coz img calls might not block downloads of other resources

Comment: Any reason you're not using [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)?

Comment: @JimSchubert actually in `window.onbeforeunload` I couldn't execute anything except a return statement. Can you post me how would u do with it?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of what you described, you can have that script loaded in your page or parent window (you are saying it is an iframe right?) and run a function on window.unload:

```
window.onunload = function(){
   window.top.logtime(); // if it is in the parent, or 
   window.logtime() //if it is in the same window
};
```

and don't return false, unload event cannot be cancelled. (in best cases, the user gets an alert dialog that will override the return false statement.)

I think what makes this different is how fast it carries out a new function, before the body gets unloaded. Manipulating the DOM is definitely much slower than making a call.